# adjust main container width according to table width

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible ..if table width increase then its main container widths increase according to that. Is it possible ??

```
 <div class="container main-con">
    <table class="table table-hover"> <tr><td></td></tr>
     </table>
  </div>
```

here if data increase in table then table is coming outside the container. so is it possible to increase width of main container according to table width

Comment: No, containers are fixed width or fluid which means the width of the browser window. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: sir i have container in container i have table. if table data increase then table is coming outside the container

Comment: so i want to increase container width according to table width

Answer (score 0):

Having a container that is wider than the screen is almost always a very bad user experience. People (with good reason) don't like to scroll left and right. Instead you are better off making only your table scroll left/right.

You should be able to achieve this quite easily by making the table responsive. from the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive):

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally

For example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: sir dont want to use table-responsive . i have already done that

Comment: If you really desperately want your table to be wider than your screen, then don't put it in a `container`

Comment: i have put it in container ... case 1. if data width  increase in table.... then table coming outside from the container